# MySQL: the inconsistency of auto increment in id numbers

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, auto-increment, create-table

I wonder if you have come across this that the id numbers of auto increment don't arrange in correct order **when you click on Browse button on phpMyAdmin** - is it just me? Something I have set incorrectly in the db table?

For instance, when you insert a series of data into a table and you have deleted some of them as well, so when you check this table on phpMyAdmin, these data should appear in an order like this,

```
id

2
24
28
296
300
```

but in most of my tables they don't appear in orders, instead they appear in something like this,

```
id

24
300    
2
296    
28
```

as in this picture below,

[image]

Can we do something about it so that the IDs appear in the correct order?

**EDIT 1:**

I think most of you have misunderstood the issue I raided here. I mean when you click on Browser button on the phpMyAdmin to list all the data in your tables - not when you use SQL query to list the output by using `order by`.

Does it make sense?

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

This is one of my table structure - does it help you to see what is wrong in it?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `root_pages` (
  `pg_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pg_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pg_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pg_subtitle` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pg_description` text,
  `pg_introduction` text,
  `pg_content_1` text,
  `pg_content_2` text,
  `pg_content_3` text,
  `pg_content_4` text,
  `pg_order` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pg_hide` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `pg_highlight` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `pg_important` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `pg_parent` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `parent_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pg_cat_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'page category id',
  `ps_cat_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'post category id',
  `tmp_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'template id',
  `pg_backdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `pg_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `pg_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pg_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this applies to you but is your PK of type INT? If it's some sort of VARCHAR or TEXT it could order like the example you showed. And are you sure that column is actually your PK? Post the SHOW CREATE TABLE output of the table and it might become clearer.

And which storage engine are you using. The default order of a select is insert order for MYISAM and PK for InnoDB if I remember correctly. This would also depend of your version of MySql. To be sure in all circumstances you SHOULD use ORDER BY in your select statement.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I just posted one of my table structure above. thanks!

Comment: PK is primary key. I see from your create statment that you are using MYISAM as the storage engine. The default order of selects for that engine is the order in which the records were inserted. So that's why you get the result you are getting. The only way to make sure that you order your select by your primary key then is by using a ORDER BY in your select query. Since you are only interested about the default behaviour of phpmyadmin you can only accomplish thos by altering the code of phpmyadmin. You could try to change your storage engine to InnoDB that uses PK ordering by default in select

Answer (score 7):

You can order your output however you like: `ORDER BY id ASC`.

Records in a table have no inherent order.

Comment: asc is technically not required, but +1 for mentioning that there is no default order.

Comment: @Omar: `ASC` is explicit and legible, and if you definitely want ascending order then there's no reason to omit it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want them ordered by the ID then you have to use an `order by` clause when selecting.

With SQL, the sets returned by `select` are unordered unless you specify what order you want them in.

You should assume that the actual order will be random unless you specify it. In reality, it's arbitrary rather than random but changes to the table content can easily change the order.